# Load Random array from firebase to list

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So I have been quite successful in all my Firestore use cases but this is messing me up.

So I have this collection that has a bunch of documents, each with an array of strings.

What I am trying to accomplish is to populate my list with a random array (one string per line) when I press a button.
Not very successful, and this is as far I got.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
        val workoutNewList = workoutListView
    val workoutNewListAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, workoutList)
    workoutNewList.adapter = workoutNewListAdapter


    val docRef = db.collection("Benchmark Wods Girls")

    docRef.addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { value, e ->

        if (e != null) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Listen failed.", e)
            return@EventListener
        }

        for (document in value.documents) {
            val data = document.data
            val categories = data["exercises"] as String



            workoutList.add(categories)
        }

        randomWorkoutBtn.setOnClickListener {



        var workoutCount: Int = workoutList.size
        var randomWorkoutNumber: Int = Random().nextInt(workoutCount)


        val randomWorkout = ArrayList<String>()
        for (i in 1..9) {
            randomWorkout.add(workoutList.get(randomWorkoutNumber))
        } }


        workoutNewListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
```

---

**EDIT: DATABSE STRUCTURE**

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UcrJ.png)

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Comment: Sorry Alex. I am going to put a screenshot on my post. Look after EDIT

Comment: Done :).. can you see?

Comment: To get a random document that contains the array that you are looking for, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377381/select-random-document-from-firestore/48379115)**. It is in Java but you can simply convert to Kotlin.

Comment: My solution is based on that... but I don't know what to do on the for loop :/ Could you show me something pleasE? thanks

Comment: Yoi cannot solve this just in the for loop. Take as an example my answer from that post, but instead of creating a list of student objects, just create a list of arrays.

Comment: still breaks if I add a list with an array :/

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, I am still stuck. Can't you give me a hint? :/ Thanks

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I tried many thing only to revert back to what currently is here. I saw the range was from 1..9, which is wrong since I only want 1. so I put for(i in 1..1) I added the random number to it... I tried to create the array but the it was giving me errors... Really lost

Comment: With what I have the app breaks

Comment: no idea at all? :(