# How to make a request to receive random documents based on id? limit(10)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firestore(web)
Help me write a request for random documents based on ID
[image]

Can I do this without getting the entire collection?

```js
const questions = [];
    const docRef = db.collection('ru').doc(category).collection('questions');
    try {
      const doc = await docRef.get();
      doc.forEach((item) => {
        questions.push(item.data());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
```

Comment: You should write some code to show what you have tried.  It sounds like maybe you need to get all the documents in the collection, then iterate through them.

Comment: Can I do this without getting the entire collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)

Comment: I did not understand this example

Comment: Hope this link will be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58023128/1318946