# Random query on firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app, and I am using firestore, I want to obtain the documents of a collection and that its result brings them in a random way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish correct. But if you want to retrieve a random document from a collection, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection

Comment: And **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377381/select-random-document-from-firestore/48379115)** is how you can achieve the same thing with Android.