# Firestore query on collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have list of Collection IDs. Is there any way I can query and get all the documents under these collection ids? without iterating to each id in the list.
[image]

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you're asking how to run a query across multiple collections, the answer is that you can't (yet). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections

Comment: I only see a single collection (user) which contains a few documents represented by their document ids. What do you really want to query? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, There is only one collection user. In my code I have list of document ids form this user collection. I want to query this collection in a way so that it gives me all the documents that matches the ids in the list.


List list = ['C0smTfprmfdw...', 'test', 'yhwDu2qvTRX...']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment, I understand that you want to get all documents within a single collection and not to query multiple collections, which is not possbile for the moment in Firestore.

If you have a list of ids, then simply iterate over it and create for each id in the list the corresponding `DocumentReference` and then add all those references to a `List<DocumentReference>`. After that, iterate over the new list and for each reference create a `Task` and then add all those Tasks objects to `List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>>`.

In the end, just pass the list of Tasks to Tasks's [whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        for (Object object : list) {
            YourObject yb = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(YourObject.class);
            Log.d("TAG", yb.getPropertyName);
        }
    }
});
```

In code it looks like my answer from this post:

- [Android Firestore convert array of document references to List<Pojo>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892766/android-firestore-convert-array-of-document-references-to-listpojo/51897261)

Comment: I just edited the question and put a line (I should have put it earlier, sorry) that I do not want to iterate the id list (List<String>) that I have to get the each doc ref one by one. I am looking for a way if there is anything that I can do in singe query call....

Comment: To answer your new question. "Is there any way I can query and get all the documents under these collection ids? without iterating to each id in the list. " **No, there is not!** The only way is as explained in my answer. You need to itarate the list in order to get those documents.

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo for your time