# How to query a list of strings instead of a single string and get a list of results from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have a list of IDs of favorite items of a user locally stored in a list of strings. Now when user opens his favorite section the app needs to fetch all the items in the local favorite list from Cloud Firestore. Now what I see is only query that accepts a field and only a string (in my case only a single id of favorite item at a time).

Is there a way to pass the list of IDs as a Query in a single operation and get the result. What I am doing now is passing the IDs to `RecylerView` adapter and fetching it one by one in the `BindViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    db.whereEqualTo("imageId",mUploads.get(position))
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            List<Upload> uploadsList = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(Upload.class);
            Upload uploadCurrent = uploadsList.get(0);

            holder.materialCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(uploadCurrent.getImageColor()));
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.imageView);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i don't believe there is. I'm pretty sure you'd have to do a for loop and pass the data to your adapter and notify  it or just continue doing what you're doing.

Comment: Repeating the data fetch every time in the adapter is a little overhead right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass the list of IDs as a Query in a single operation and get the result.

No, there is not not. You cannot pass a list or an array of strings to your query and get the results in one go. When calling `get()` on a `Query` object, the object that is returned is of type `Task`. Iterate through your list, create those Task objects and add all of them to a `List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>>` and then pass that list to Tasks's [whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method as it is explained in my answer from the following post:

- [Android Firestore convert array of document references to List<Pojo>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892766/android-firestore-convert-array-of-document-references-to-listpojo/51897261)

**Edit:**

You should iterate through your list of strings and create the Task objects.

```
Task<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotTask = collRef.document(stringFromList).get();
```

So at every iteration add the Task object to a list of tasks:

```
List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

At the end just pass `tasks` list to `whenAllSuccess()` method, that's it.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't quite understood that.The list of my IDs in List<String>  and I need to get result list as of the form List<Uploads>. My collections name is "uploads" and the field of document that should be matched to is "imageId"

Comment: Check also the duplicate, it's the exact same thing, right?

Comment: But we should pass a field and its corresponding value as query in that case right?

Comment: Please see my updated answer and tell me if it works.