# is there any way to choose a random document in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, random, get, document

I'm trying to make an app that will appear happy phrases like: "You are very important; Fight as you can, but never give up" and if you click the "again" button another phrase will appear. But I'm stuck on how I'm going to show these phrases and how to choose them randomly. I'm new to programming now, sorry for any stupid questions.

My initial idea was to create a database in firebase where I would put the phrases and thus somehow randomly get them.

If you could, I would like you to talk about a way to do this in flutter, because that's where I have my project.

Comment: Maybe this [amswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377381/select-random-document-from-firestore) will help to get an idea.