# How to fetch a random document from firestore collection, when I have extra where() criteria with inequalities?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to write a nodejs cloud function to fetch a random document from my 'profiles' collection in firestore like this:

```
randomProfile = await admin.firestore().collection('profiles')
.where('fieldA', '==', ...)
.where('fieldB', '==', ...)
.where('fieldC', '==' ...)
.where('fieldD', '==',...)
.where('fieldE', '<=', ...)
.where('fieldE', '>=', ...)
.offset(random)
.limit(1)
.get()
```

Since I'm using up the `<=` and `>=` for `fieldE`, and since firestore allows inequalities on [one field only](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), I'm trying to use the offset clause to get a random document.

My problem is: How do I assign a value to `random` such that I don't have an "out of bounds" condition? In other words, I don't want `random` to be greater than the number of documents that can ever be returned by the query...

Please help! This is a make-or-break issue for continuing with firestore in my current project, and I've come too far!

Note: I can't use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection/46801925#46801925) because of the `fieldE` problem.

Comment: I did. I've linked to that answer in the last line of my post. Perhaps you missed it and why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: terribly sorry I have to clue how I missed that.