# How to get random and unique document from Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on true false quiz and want to fetch one by one question (document) from firestore collection. I checked one answer in stackoverflow here ([Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)) but its for swift, also I really didn't understand it.

My database structure is simple, its have only 2 fields, 1. Question texts and 2. True / false

I tried to fetch simple query in firestore but its not working perfectly.

Please help me.

Comment: @Alex Mamo what about unnecessary reads? If I have 100 documents and I only need 10. What is the read cost in this case?

Comment: In that case, just add all the needed ids to a single document. And get the random one from it.

Comment: @AlexMamo please explain it. I also read your answer at above said link but I really don't understand. If possible, please explain with example. It would be helpful for thousands of developers.