# Query elements in differnet orders without doublons in Firestore

Tags: database, algorithm, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing a quizz and want to fetch questions from a Firestore.

How can I query questions one by one from the DB in a different order between players but being sure that I never show twice the same question to the same player.

Is it possible to give an array of IDs that I already fetched ? Or is there another solution that can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Firebase for that. The first approach that comes to mind would be to track what questions you've already asked, and find a next question at random with the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection/46801925#46801925). Then if you've already used that question, find another random one.

Comment: Yes, I had a similar approach in mind but if the player already played a lot, it's possible that we need to fetch a lot of questions before finding one that he didn't play before...

Comment: I think I'll fetch questions by batches then randomly select questions in that batch locally.

Comment: Sounds like it'd have the same problem, just at a different scale. But if that works for you, definitely go for it.