# Unable to return random Firestore document from collection

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuefire

I am building a web-app using Nuxt and am having a hard time trying to get a single random message from my messages collection in Firestore.

I have tried using a method to return a random message as well as just as randomizing an index value of the array in the `messages` object.

To better explain, this is what my current script tag looks like of my Messages.vue component:

```
<script>
import {db} from '../plugins/firebase'
    export default {
        firestore() {
            return {
                messages: db.collection("messages")
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                messages: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            randomMessage() {
                var randomMessage = this.messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.messages.length)];
                return randomMessage
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

The `randomMessage()` method does return a random message object out of the collection, but it is the entire object and I just want the `.text` propery of `message`. In other words, `{{messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.messages.length)]}}`works in returning a random message document from Firestore, but when I use `{{messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.messages.length)].text`, I receive an error:

```
Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

I have also tried following Dan McGrath's answer in this thread without success:

[Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)

I am not sure how to implement the Wrap-around solution in my Nuxt project. When I try to use that solution as a method in my script export, I get a syntax error.

The full repo can be found here: https://github.com/SIeep/motivation-app

Any help or guidance is appreciated!