# Flutter - How to get a specific ID of a random document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As you can see in the picture, collection 'Communities' got multiple documents inside of it which I managed to read all the data that is inside of it by applying this line of code:

```
 late QuerySnapshot Comms = await _firestore.collection('User').doc(User.userID).collection("Communities").get();
```

then applied this for the needed fields

```
 Text( Comms.docs[index].get("nameOfCommunity").toString(),),
```

but how can I get the ID of the collection that I got the data from?

[image]

Comment: You can get some idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302507/flutter-firebase-how-to-get-random-document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore provides a property called `id` on the document snapshot, which you can access that in your case like this

```
comms.docs[index].id
```

Check this reference [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+get+doc+id+in+firebase)