# Read random user firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever a user uses the Firebase Auth to register on my app, I create a document in a `users` collection of Firestore that stores metadata such as pseudo, userType, gender ...

To do that, the document id is exactly the same as the `uid` provided automatically by Firebase Auth (from the user `UserRecord` object)

Now, my app needs to fetch a user randomly from the `users` collection in Firestore.

I read [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection) but this post suggest that I create the ID myself. The app is already built using the FirebaseAuth generated ID so what is the solution ?

Comment: The approach will be the same as in the answer you linked: generate a random UID value client-side, and then find the closest one to that in the database by ordering by UID, and starting at the random value you generated.

Comment: @tsr if an answer worked would you kindly mark as the best answer?

Answer (score 2):

A common practice in firestore is to create a "--Stats--" document within a collection (--Stats-- being the document id). This document can house information about the collection (number of documents, last updated, collection privileges etc.).

In your case, you could use cloud functions/triggers to keep tract of the total number of users in the users collection and add the id of a new user to a "userIds" array. You could keep both of these fields in the users collection's --Stats-- document. This way, when you wanted to get a random user, you could randomly generate a number betweeen 0 and the document count, then use it as an index of the userIds array. I might look something like this:

```
var usersCollectionRef= db.collection("users");

usersCollectionRef.doc("--Stats--").get().then((doc) => {

    let numberOfUsers = doc.data().numberOfUsers; 
    let userIdArray = doc.data().userIds; 
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numberOfUsers + 1));

    return usersCollectionRef.doc(userIdArray[randomNumber]).get();

}).then((doc) => {
   ...do something with the user's document
})
```

Comment: I guess you dont need the numberOfUsers then, just count the userIds