# Is there any standard firestore query to get random documents?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get multiple random documents from a dynamic collection. Until know, I have thought to do it using simple queries, something like this:

```
 Pseudocode
 
 arr = [];
 while (arr.length < 5) {
     // Start the query at a random position
     startAt = Math.random() * collection.size;
     randomDoc = await dbRef.startAt(startAt).limit(1).get( ... );
     arr.push(randomDoc);
 }
```

Here, firstly, I have to get the collection size, as it can be 0 or bigger. Then, select a random document using a kind of "db random pointer/index".

My question is if there is any way to get the same result but without all the loop stuff, only with the query syntax.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clever use of startAt and limit!
As you can see in [the reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#methods), there are no built-in methods that would return random documents.

In order to avoid the loop, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const indices = getRandomIndices(collection.size);
const docs = await Promise.all(indices.map(i => {
    return dbRef.startAt(i).limit(1).get();
}));
```

And for the getRandomIndices, I suggest: create an array [0, 1, 2, ...], shuffle it as describe in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/6016470), and slice its 5 first elements.

Comment: How do you get the collection size exactly?

Comment: Hi @iusting, there is no built-in way to get a collection size, but I wrote an article on how to achieve this: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-documents-in-firestore-a0527f792d04

Comment: That being said, I think that keeping the size of a collection only for the purpose of picking random elements is overkill. It can be achieved in a simpler way, for example by storing a random number in every documents and querying based on this number.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I asked because OP mentions having a dynamic collection and the `collection.size` part misleaded me at least into thinking such property exists. I love the random number suggestion! Ended up implementing it based on a Dan McGrath solution here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection.