# Is it possible to add a subcollection to a collection without adding document in Firestore?

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

[image: model example]

I want to create a database model for posts like the above image.

```
posts(collection) > categories(document) > c1(collection) > post_id(document) > post_data
```

In that case if I perform any queries like `whereEqualTo` or `whereLessThan` on `c1` collection it works fine.

But in the other case,

```
posts(collection) > all(document) > post_id(collection) > post_data
```

In that case I want to perform queries on `all`, but I can't because it's a document.

So is there any ways to add a subcollection to a collection without adding document or adding a dummy document/collection like following is the only way to do it?

```
posts(collection) > all(document) > xyz(collection) > post_id(document) > post_data
```

Need help :(

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: Query is kind of similar to the "wrap-around" section of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801925/8207701. Using cloud functions I'll get random posts (one week old limit) from user's preferred categories and "all" section, mix it up and then send it to client.

Comment: @AlexMamo I can also achieve what I want if I use different root collections for categories and all posts or use a dummy collection name like the last mentioned code. But as a beginner I just want to know if there're any cleaner ways to model it.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for now, you can only add documents to a collection.
Your solution may be to restructure your database. Now it looks a bit strange, you double save your data.

I suggest you to do in this way:

```
POSTS:
     P1:
          category: c1
          data: somedata
     P2:
          category: c1
          data: somedata
     P3:
          category: c2
          data: somedata
```

After that you can do a query `whereEqualTo("category", c1)` and you will get all documents from the category c1.

Comment: I need to perform some complex queries on both "category" and "all" collection. So using model like that isn't so flexible for me. But in the mentioned code, `POSTS > ALL > P1, P2, P3` "All" is a document. So it's not possible to use queries like whereEqualTo("category", c1) right? Or am I missing something? Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Can you tell me a couple of words about complex query? What do you need to search for? I have made my answer a bit incorrect, now I have fixed it