# Firestore admin pagination without parameters (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I would like to paginate through all of the documents in one of my collections. However I don't need a search parameter like 'population' or any other one. I simply want to load all items in the collection in batches, in no particular order. The documentation only shows with a search parameter. If you need more insight let me know.

Comment: Can you share a link to what you are referring by search parameter in docs?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to not using `orderBy()` method in your query then you can just omit that method. In that case your queries will be sorted in ascending order by document ID. You can still use `limit()` method to get first few documents and then use snapshot of the last document to get the next batch.

```js
let lastDocSnap = null

async function getNextBatch(lastDoc) {
  const query = await db.collection('collection')
  if (lastDocSnap) query = query.startAt(lastDoc) // pass last doc snapshot
  query = query.limit(10) // add limit
  
  const snapshot = await query.get()
  lastDocSnap = snapshot[snapshot.size-1] // setting new last doc
  return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data)
}

getNextBatch(lastDocSnap)
```

As mentioned above, these will be sorted based on their document IDs as you are not explicitly specifying any field using orderBy.

[Use a document snapshot to define the query cursor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor)

Comment: If you are looking for getting random documents, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)