# Get random documents from Firestore using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have read a  documents about random java, swift but JS random document firestore i can't find and I see this problem not yet for JS?

swift

```
postsRef.whereField("random", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: random)
                   .order(by: "random")
                   .limit(to: 1)
```

JS

```
postsRef.where("random", ">=", random)
                   .order("random")
                   .limit(1)
```

is this correct?

Comment: The logic should remain the same irrespective of the language imo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection

You're right. I tried converting from swift to JS and it seems to be wrong

Comment: i updated my question. You can see and give me your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript (remove the types if you use Javascript) version for getting random documents using random integers (and wrap-around). This answer uses Cloud function for testing but essentially you just need to copy the `getDocuments` function.

```ts
export const getRandomDoc = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    const randomDocs = await getDocuments(2)
    return res.send(randomDocs)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send(err)
  }
});

const getDocuments = async (count: number): Promise<Array<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>> => {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
  const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("col").where("rInt", ">=", randomNum).limit(count).get()
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    return getDocuments(count)
  }
  return snapshot.docs.map(d => d.data())
}
```

Whenever you add a new document to that collection, add the `rInt` field along with it which is an integer between 0 to 10000 (both inclusive). You pass the number of documents you need in the `getDoucments` function. It will fetch N consecutive matched docs though as this uses `limit()` method.

In the query we look for documents where `rInt` is greater than or equal to that random number generated using `Math.random()` and limit the results to `count` parameter passed in the function. If the snapshot is empty we retry the function. (It'll be worth to add a logic which makes this function repeat only N number of time else recursion will take it's time).

---

Using `.limit()` as in the function above will end up returning N documents in a row. By default, docs will be ordered by their document ID unless you specify any particular field using `orderBy` method. Instead making a separate request for each doc will increase the randomicity.

```ts
/**
 * @param {number} count - number of documents to retrieve
 * @param {number} loopNum - number of times the loop is being repeated. Defaults to 0 
 * @param {Array<any>} curDocs - array of documents matched so far. Defaults to an empty array
 * @returns 
 */ 
const getDocuments = async (count: number, loopNum: number, curDocs: Array<any>): Promise<Array<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>> => {
  // Creating an array of requests to get documents
  const requests = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // New random number for each request
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
    console.log(`Random Num: ${randomNum}`);
    requests.push(admin.firestore().collection("col").where("rInt", ">=", randomNum).limit(1).get())
    // limit is set to 1 so each request will return 1 document only
  }
  
  // Using Promise.all() to run all the promises
  const snapshots = await Promise.all(requests)
  
  // Removing empty snapshots
  const filteredSnapshots = snapshots.filter(d => !d.empty)

  // Creating an array of doc data
  const matchedDocs = filteredSnapshots.map(doc => doc.docs[0].data())
  
  // If documents received are less than requested,
  // repeat the function
  if (matchedDocs.length !== count) {
    // If the function is repeated 5 times,
    // return with whatever has matched so far
    if (loopNum + 1 === 5) {
      console.log("Returning CurDocs")
      return curDocs
    }
    return getDocuments(count, loopNum + 1, [...curDocs, ...matchedDocs])
  }
  
  // Return if you get requested num of docs in first go
  return snapshots.map(d => d.docs[0].data())
}

// Calling the function
getDocuments(5, 0, [])
```

Do note that you can use [`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator if you are requesting less than or equal to 10 documents. *The in operator combines up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR.*

---

*For original version (swift) by [@Dan McGrath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153407/dan-mcgrath), [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection).*