# How to get random documents in Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a random profile link that is stored in my Firestore's Document

The structure of data is like this

```
Profiles-
    documentId-
             randomProfileLink

    documentId-
             randomProfileLink

    documentId-
             randomProfileLink

   //and so on...
```

**How can I get this randomly**
please help me out with this question

Comment: Have you checked these answers? [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection) and [Get random documents from Firestore using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463784/get-random-documents-from-firestore-using-javascript)

Comment: yes but I don't understand clearly

Comment: If you don't understand the existing answers to the question that you've duplicated, you should explain more specifically what isn't working the way you expect, or where you are stuck with the problem.