# How to get random value from firestore using firebase javascript function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing supporting method in firebase function. I need to get only random company name from the companies collections rather the given company where I getting only first value from the collection.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
async function selectCompany(companyName) {
  const vouchercompany = [];
  try {
    await db.collection('companies')
      .where('companyName', '!=', companyName)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          vouchercompany.push(doc.data())
        })
      })
    return vouchercompany;
  } catch (error) {
    json(error.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking [how to get a random document from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)?

Comment: Please describe your specific problem in the question title.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should have a master document that contains an array of all company names and their relevant document ID or relevant collection name.

Create a Firestore document "_index" inside your companies collection as a master index

```
companies/_index
      // (keep a total count of all companies, helpful if you need to scale over 10k companies)
      count: 1200,
      // (An array can hold multiple items without breaking a sweat)
      companyIndex: [companyName + : + documentID]
```

Simple read the document and iterate over the `companyIndex` item. once you have picked your random items, you can split it with:

```js
const value = item.split(':');
const companyName = value[0];
const docReference = value[1];
```

to add a company, you can use `arrayUnion` with `[companyName, documentId].join(':')`
you can find the relevant methods to [update arrays here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

This allows you to make more dynamic and randomized results without any of the problems existing random solutions have. That being said, I would not use this for something with documents in the potential millions such as user posts or comments.