# How to get random data from firebase function from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get random data from collection expect the given value.

```
async function selectCompany(companyName) {
   const vouchercompany = [];
try{
    await db.collection('companies')
    .where ('companyName' ,'!=' , companyName)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   vouchercompany.push(doc.data())
      })
    })
    return vouchercompany;
} catch(error) { json(error.message) }
```

Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Getting random documents from a collection is pretty definitively described here: [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)

But since the [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) in the Firestore documentation say:

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

That means you can't use one field for a random index, and then still filter for `!=` on `companyName`. You'll either have to store both values in the same field, or do the filtering for `companyName` in your application code after retrieving the random documents.