# Firestore get data from a random generated document

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore like this

```
ppl (collection)
   1 (document)
    school(collection)
        jhdsfjhdsgfjh (random generated document)
               jobname(collection field)
                  teacher:1 (collection field1)
                  advisor:2 (collection field2)
```

I want to extract teacher and advisor in a JSON file but I am not able to

my code so far:

```
 doc_ref = db.collection(u'ppl').document('1')
 doc = doc_ref.get
 docuout =  doc_ref.collection('school').document().collection().stream()

 document_output=docuout.to_dict()
```

it's returning an empty document_output. Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `document()` without parameters, it generates a reference to a new/non-existing document. So you're trying to stream a subcollection of a non-existing document, which explains why you don't get any results.

If you want to get the subcollection for a specific document, specify the ID for that document in the call to `document("id here")` as shown in the docs on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python_2). If you don't know the ID of the document, you will need to know something else that uniquely identifies the document and can then [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to find the document.

If you want to get a random document from the `school` collection, have a look at Dan's excellent answer here: [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection)

Comment: Is there anyway to find the value of the random document id ? I dont know the ID of it because it was automatically generated

Comment: If you know something else that identifies the document, you can find the document ID using a query. See the link I posted in my answer for the docs on that.

Comment: Hey @J1701. Any updates there?