# Return query results in randomly distributed order from Firestore or Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I want my query results to return in a random order when doing a query to the Google Datastore such as this.

```
Query<Entity> query =
    Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
        .setKind("Task")
        .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("done", false))
        .build();
```

Is there any guarantee that the results will be in randomly distributed every time you make the query? Or do I have to implement other logic for results to come back randomly?

I assume the same applied to Firestore queries such as in Swift:

```
let query = citiesRef.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
```

Comment: There is no API in Firestore to have it returns results in a random order. For the best options, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the link. I have a follow up question: If documents are added using auto-generated ids, and you query for one document, is there some sort of order to it? (whether random or not) I am trying to understand how the datastore/firestore selects the one document.

Comment: If you don't specify an order, the documents are returned in order of document ID (afaik).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen By that you mean, the lowest alphanumeric document ID should be returned first?